# How to convert date from one format to another in Php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, datetime-format

How to convert date from "2011-08-01 04:01:45" to "Mon, 01 Aug 2011 05:37:45 -0400" in Php

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 5):

```
$newDate = date('r', strtotime('2011-08-01 04:01:45'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use the strtotime function in php to parse the date string and then the date function to print it in whatever format you'd like.

```
<?php

$orig = "2011-08-01 04:01:45";

$timestamp = strtotime($orig);

echo date("D, d M Y H:i:s O",$timestamp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't going to solve your problem but a really fast method of using dates and information is to store the time using a unix time stamp. This is an integer value of seconds counting from the time (1970 -1 second).

It will allow you to format dates in a much simpler manner using something like:

```
<?php date('d-m-Y', $unixTimeStamp); ?>
```

This method is also much faster when it comes to comparing times.