# how to convert date format MySQL php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

how to covert date format in table mysql using php, From this format 2016-07-02T17:04:18+00:00 To Sat, 02 Jul 2016 17:04:18 GMT ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: dont store dates as strings use a date type

Answer (score -1):

read the value from mysql to variable [info](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

then use;

```
$in = "2016-07-02T17:04:18+00:00";
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$out = date("D, d M Y G:i:s e",strtotime($in));
echo $out;
```

write the value back if desired [info](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

assumed that value you listed is varchar as it doesnt appear as a standard mysql datetime format. [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) and that you understand how to query the database.

if the value is datetime as your post seems to lead too. then try the code, as strtotime should understand the format fine. but the code will be to convert and output the date elsewhere, not write back into mysql as dateime as it doesnt work like that.

also see;

[Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php?rq=1)

[How to convert date from one format to another in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963848/how-to-convert-date-from-one-format-to-another-in-php?rq=1)